# Not able to get Organization > Settings > Timezone within Azure Devops Services

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops

I'm developing a tool to automate some features within azure devops services. At this point i'm trying to see what the time zone is in a organization. By following a call (made when loading the page) i was able to get all timezones, owner information and more. What i did not found is what the selected timezone is.

**My question is how can i see or where can i find what the current timezone is.**

**Call used created with Postman:**

**Methode:** POST https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery?api-version=5.1-preview.1

```
{
"contributionIds": [
    "ms.vss-admin-web.organization-admin-overview-delay-load-data-provider"
],
"dataProviderContext": {
    "properties": {}
}
}
```

[image]
This is what i recreated in postman with the call that was discribed above.
What i try to figure out is how i can see what time zone is set in the organization (left in picture).
This i will have to do using a call because the system wil be automaticly check if it is set correctly.
However i cannot find a property that holds the value of the time zone.
How can i see what time zone is set.

Comment: Not sure but this seems has been forbidden for some reason, you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366588/12722389) and will find there's timeZone displayname and if in the response body, but i have tried the same operations which get no these things. Maybe you can have a try too.

Comment: Hi @YangShen-MSFT, I know it is not supported by the api and SDK.
The tread you posted is what i tried above (right in screenshot) is the result.
It will give all time zones with the displayname. However the returned data is not showing what timezone is ectualy set and that is the problem i have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it's not in the `HierarchyQuery` but in the `?__rt=fps&__ver=2` where you can find the chosen timezone value:

[image]

[image]

I tested this in postman and can get the timezone value successfully:

`https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_settings/?__rt=fps&__ver=2`

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you so much!
It works perfect. If i may ask how did you find it?

Comment: Press `Ctrl+F` and search for "timezone" and i checked all the searched result one by one and finally found it in the `?__rt=fps&__ver=2`, simple and crude:P.